# How to attach elasticsearch license using puppet

Tags: elasticsearch, puppet, elasticsearch-6.8

I am trying to use the 6.4.0 elastic-elasticsearch module for puppet to attach a license to my elasticsearch nodes.
This is a sample of my code:

```
class { 'elasticsearch':
    version          => "6.x.x",
    manage_repo      => true,
    datadir          => '/some/dir',
    security_plugin  => 'x-pack',
    license => lookup($lookup_array.map |$value| { "$value/license" }, {'default_value' => undef}),
    service_provider => 'systemd',
    api_basic_auth_username => "user",
    api_basic_auth_password => "password",
    validate_tls            => false,
    config           => {}
}
```

when I run the puppet agent I get this error (raised by elastic_rest.rb):

> Error: /Stage[main]/Elasticsearch::License/Elasticsearch_license[xpack]: Could not evaluate: Received 'end of file reached' from the Elasticsearch API. Are your API settings correct?

How do I troubleshoot this?
Is there a working example of the usage of this feature?

Comment: This appears to either be an incompatibility between the version of ES and the Puppet provider, or incorrect usage of the class. Can you link to the module you are using to verify with its documentation and/or source code?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am using this module https://forge.puppet.com/elastic/elasticsearch/readme and puppet 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in my case, setting the `api_protocol` to "https" solved this.